# Stripe.net PaymentMethodGetOptions doesn't have any members

Tags: stripe-payments

in .net Core I'm trying to retrieve a payment method by calling

```
var service = new PaymentMethodService();
return await service.GetAsync(paymentMethodId);
```

I'd like to add the `Customer` and `Type` in the PaymentMethodGetOptions as expected by `service.Get()` or `service.GetAsync()` methods, but the class is empty: [link to github repo](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Services/PaymentMethods/PaymentMethodGetOptions.cs).

> **Note**: [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer) refers to a `PaymentMethodRetreiveOptions` but that doesn't exists in the library or Github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the API reference is not up-to-date.

To retrieve a paymentMethod of a given customer, you should use the [CustomerService.RetrievePaymentMethod](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Services/Customers/CustomerService.cs#L109) function instead. In addition, the `type` param is not accepted anymore.